# 3 hydration errors i am using next js i think it is wth the modalfile

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js13

this is page,tsx

```
"use client"
import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import Page from './../(auth)/(routes)/sign-up/[[...sign-up]]/page';
import { UserButton } from "@clerk/nextjs";
import { Modal } from "@/components/ui/modal";

const SetupPage=()=> {
  return (
    <div className="p-4">
    <Modal title="Test" description="Test Desc"   isOpen onClose={()=>{}} >
      Children
      </Modal>
     </div>
  )
}
export default SetupPage;
```

the below is modal.tsx

```
"use client"

import {
    Dialog,
    DialogContent,
    DialogDescription,
    DialogHeader,
    DialogTitle,
    DialogFooter,
  } from "@/components/ui/dialog"

  
  interface ModalProps {
    title: string;
    description: string;
    isOpen: boolean;
    onClose: () => void;
    children?: React.ReactNode;
  }
  
  export const Modal: React.FC<ModalProps> = ({
    title,
    description,
    isOpen,
    onClose,
    children
  }) => {
    const onChange = (open: boolean) => {
      if (!open) {
        onClose();
      }
    };
  
    return ( 
      <Dialog open={isOpen} onOpenChange={onChange}>
        <DialogContent>
          <DialogHeader>
            <DialogTitle>{title}</DialogTitle>
            <DialogDescription>
              {description}
            </DialogDescription>
          </DialogHeader>
          <div>
            {children}
          </div>
        </DialogContent>
      </Dialog>
    );
  };
```

when running i am having 3 hydration errors something to do with modal i think but not able to figure out
.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGZFL.png)

i walked through all the code and next js documentation i am not able t o figurre it out